# iOS : Roboto Condensed through Interface builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, custom-font

I have a weird issue here... An app uses some custom font (Roboto Condensed for instance).

I added my font to my project. They are associated with the target. They are declared in the info.plist and the typo is right (copy/paste from the original files) and they contain the extension of course. They are in the "Copy ressources" of the build phase, they are part of the Font Family when I log them but enumerating fonts, they work through IB, and they are not set when the app is running... The fonts were download from the latest version on the Google website.

Weirdest thing : I have other custom font, and they are working.
Even weirder : if I set the font programmatically, it works...

It seems that it is related to IB (font name, family?)
I'm running out of options here. Have you encountered this kind of behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: You try **Editor -> Refresh All Views** or close and reopen IB?

Comment: Quite xcode and restart it

Comment: Considering everything I've tried, of course I tried to restart Xcode. Not working.

Comment: Than the name that you gave of font is incorrect.Try download the font from another source and it should work

Comment: The actual name is RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf and I tried 2 different websites including the Google one (they are editing the Roboto font family btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any solution. The only workaround is to have outlets for every font specific view and set it into code :-/